# Keep remote objects updated

Tags: java, collections, tcp, client-server, rpc

Having two object **A**, **B**, of the same Class (for example HashMaps).

At different computers connected by internet

One (**A**) is the source and the other (**B**) is just as an updated copy...

*Is there a standard/recommended way to keep them "connected" or "updated"?*

**Example**

I am using a TCP connection and writeObject

> ObjectOutputStream bufferObj = new ObjectOutputStream (out);
>
> bufferObj.writeObject(A)

and in the copy side something like this

> ObjectInputStream bufferObj = new ObjectInputStream(in);
>
> Object B = bufferObj.readObject();

But this have the problem that the *whole object* is sent in every synchronization
(for example periodically or everytime a modification occur)

I would like a way of sending **only the differences (specially useful for Java collections)**, but knowing the difference is not an easy thing at least

I would like to have something like this (overly simple/optimistic scheme)

At the server source

> ObjectA.serverUpdatesWarehouseAt(Port);

At the client copy

> ObjectTemp.updateItRemotelyFrom(IP,Port);
>
> ObjectB.merge(ObjectTemp); //update the differences adding/deleting as needed

Is anything like this already made  ? so here I am, trying to avoid reinvent the wheel

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might benefit from a Distributed Hash Map ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table ).

There are quite a few frameworks which provide such functionality - http://code.google.com/p/hazelcast/ is one example.

At the risk of stating the obvious - if your update rate is high you can use up a lot of bandwidth keeping the two in sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you use RMI you can have a distributed object, so you don't have to worry about keeping them updated at all. Once you have a reference to the object (on the client) it is automagically kept in sync with the server's object.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org) which does exactly this kind of thing. They allow creation of shared objects between JVM which are kept synchronized.